# how to find a file witch timestamp path

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, timestamp, nightwatch.js

During my nightwatch.js test i will download a .csv file. This file has a time stamp in its name. now i have to read the file. how can i find out the current time to search the file with the time stamp?
the file name looks like: YYMMDD_HHMMSS

```
browser.execute(function() {
  return window.now;
}, [], function(result) {
  console.log('result:', result.value);
  console.log('type:', typeof result.value);
})
```

i figured out this is how to get the date but how can I separate the values?

Comment: would the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object help?

Comment: the problem is if i use the date object the time is "false" because the whole process is longer than 1 sec.

Comment: using Date object doesn't take more than 1 second ... and what "time" is "false"?

Comment: whel how should i discribe. I first generate the file name then i use the file to do stuff. the problem is now nightwatch checks the code befor excuting and surprise it doesent find a file with the time stamp because it dosent exist at this point